# apache test page shows up on non-apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, django, gunicorn

I have a very weird bug on my hands. I'm running a Django server with Nginx and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't installed Apache ANYWHERE on my server. But if I load the website, the test page for a server running Apache on CentOS appears, and I have *neither* CentOS nor Apache installed on the server whatsoever. What's going on with my server, and how do I get the test page to go away?

Attached is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csdab.png) of the Apache test page that appears on the website.

UPDATE: It appears that Apache *is* installed on my local machine. Would purging it do the trick?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem. What is the url you are trying?

Comment: the url is nydkc11.org

Comment: Doesn't really matter what graphic is on the web server default page. Apache is installed. There is no problem here.

Comment: No, my point is that Apache isn't installed anywhere on my server, yet the Apache test page shows up.

Comment: I get nginx when I query netcraft: http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnydkc11.org%2F Can you do a DNS lookup from your local machine to make sure you dont have a host entry or equivalent?